# Key Violation during Append Query

Tags: sql-server

I have tried to look at the different posts for the Key Violation during Append Queries but couldn't find one that helped solve what started happening with my access database about 2 weeks ago.

This append query has been around for the past few months and has been working perfectly until 2 weeks ago. It is something I do 1x a week and this first started by rejecting 1 record 2 weeks ago, then the next time I imported there were 2 records that got rejected 1 week ago, and finally this 3rd time I'm doing it there are 124 cases that are being rejected due to a key violation and I cant seem to pinpoint what is causing the rejection.  When it happened the first few times there was only 1 or 2 records that were effected so I added their ID# (The primary key) to the main table and then re-did the import and after I did that it was able to update all of the information related to that record however this is not something I can do for 124 records.

I've tried everything I can think of including, checking the ID# field in the original file to see if there were any spaces etc, checking the ID# field in the imported file before it tries to append, removing all of the other data outside of the ID field to see if it would just import the ID field but none of those things resolved the issue. In fact the only thing I've found that helps is if I manually add the ID # to the tblPI ID field and then re-run the append ( I get one less to append which makes sense) and once I run the update queries it imports the rest of the corresponding data.

TblPI is the table I want to append the information to and the CCE Cohort is the file that i'm pulling the information from. The ID field in tblPI is the primary key and is set to "Indexed Yes (No Duplicates)" The only other indexed field is the Visit Date field which is set to "Indexed Yes (Duplicates OK)"

This is the syntax that is used for the append query and literally before 2 weeks ago there wasn't any issues occurring which is also what is so puzzling to me:

```
INSERT INTO tblPI ( ID, [911#], Deceased, DoB, Gender, [Hispanic/Latino], Race, [Employment Status], Occupation, [Marital Status], VisitDate, [Visit#] )
SELECT [CCE Cohort].ID, [CCE Cohort].[911#], [CCE Cohort].Deceased, [CCE Cohort].DoB, [CCE Cohort].Gender, [CCE Cohort].[Hispanic/Latino], [CCE Cohort].Race, [CCE Cohort].[Employment Status], [CCE Cohort].Occupation, [CCE Cohort].[Marital Status], [CCE Cohort].VisitDate, [CCE Cohort].[Visit#]
FROM [CCE Cohort] LEFT JOIN tblPI ON [CCE Cohort].[ID] = tblPI.[ID]
WHERE (((tblPI.ID) Is Null));
```

Thank you so much for any guidance! =)

Comment: are you inserting only null ID?

Comment: That's not MySQL syntax, it looks like SQL-Server.

Comment: It looks like sql server but you stated this is Access. Which DBMS are you actually using?

Comment: And you're sure there are no duplicate `[CCE Cohort].ID`s?

Comment: Run this query: `SELECT [CCE Cohort].ID, Count(*) as ct FROM FROM [CCE Cohort] LEFT JOIN tblPI ON [CCE Cohort].[ID] = tblPI.[ID]
WHERE (((tblPI.ID) Is Null)) GROUP BY [CCE Cohort].ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;`  If it returns any rows, then you are getting duplicates in the CCE Cohort table.

Comment: Milaci - Yes, I'd like it to add patients to the tblPI table that are in the CCE Cohort but are not yet in the tblPI.

Comment: Barmar and Sean Lange - I'm using access and clicked on the SQL view to get the code for the append query. Is there a better way to show this information? 

Sorry i'm a bit new to access and recently asked to take over management of this database.

Comment: Kidiskidovingogin - Yes, I've checked for duplicates and there aren't any duplicate ID#'s in the CCECohort file.

Comment: Laughing Vergil - Thank you so much for the query. I ran it and didn't get any rows back.

Comment: Any null value on CCE Cohort? Select * from cce cohort where ID is null; return any value?

Comment: Milaci - I ran this query and it didn't return any value so I don't believe there are any ID's in the CCE Cohort that are null.

Comment: Is only one thing that make key violation  error, in TblPI are just some ID that return a select query on insert. Make a select on TbIPl: select *  from TbIPI where ID in ( SELECT [CCE Cohort].ID, [CCE Cohort].[911#], [CCE Cohort].Deceased, [CCE Cohort].DoB, [CCE Cohort].Gender, [CCE Cohort].[Hispanic/Latino], [CCE Cohort].Race, [CCE Cohort].[Employment Status], [CCE Cohort].Occupation, [CCE Cohort].[Marital Status], [CCE Cohort].VisitDate, [CCE Cohort].[Visit#]
FROM [CCE Cohort] LEFT JOIN tblPI ON [CCE Cohort].[ID] = tblPI.[ID]
WHERE (((tblPI.ID) Is Null)))

Comment: Milaci - When I run the select Query it pulls the cases that are giving me key violation during the append into the query but then when I change it to an append query it still gives me the key violation error for these patients unfortunately. What could be the cause of that?

Comment: I think I've figured out that it's related to another table that has a connection to tbl PI that information also gets imported into so I'm going to look into that to see if I can figure out whats going on there. Thank you all so much for all of your help! =)